# js promise wait until resolved to continue "main"

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

How can I force a function to resolve a pending promise before using it in JavaScript

```
  generateKey(pass, iter).then(function(result) {
    Pkey = result;
  });
```

above Pkey returns `<empty string>` before resolving i could write a loop to check for non-emptiness but that seems counterintuitive, no?

and

```
  Pkey = generateKey(pass, iter);
```

returns a pending promise that is eventually fulfilled

```
function generateKey(passwd, iterations) {

  var encoder = new TextEncoder('utf-8');
  var passphraseKey = encoder.encode(passwd);
  var saltBuffer = encoder.encode("carthage");

  return crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'raw',
    passphraseKey,
    {name: 'PBKDF2'},
    false,
    ['deriveBits', 'deriveKey']
  ).then(function(key) {
//    console.log(key);
    return window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
    { "name": 'PBKDF2',
      "salt": saltBuffer,
      "iterations": iterations,
      "hash": 'SHA-256'
    },
    key,
    { "name": 'AES-CBC',
      "length": 256
    },
    true,
    [ "encrypt", "decrypt" ]
  )
  }).then(function (webKey) {
//    console.log(webKey);
    return crypto.subtle.exportKey("raw", webKey);
  }).then(function (buffer) {
//    console.log(buffer);
//    console.log(saltBuffer);
//    console.log("Private Key = " + buf2hex(buffer));
//    console.log("Salt = " + bytesToHexString(saltBuffer));
    return buffer;
  });

}



function buf2hex(buffer) { // buffer is an ArrayBuffer
  return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer), x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}



function bytesToHexString(byteArray) {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(byteArray, function(byte) {
    return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join('');
}
```

Comment: ***How can I force a function to resolve a pending promise before using it in JavaScript*** - You don't.  Javascript does not work that way.  You use `.then()` or `await` to get the resolved value from a promise.  There is no other choice.  You cannot make a function wait to return until a promise resolves.  Instead, you return the promise and the caller uses `.then()` or `await` on that promise to get its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) & [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) as below

```
async function generateKey(passwd, iterations) {...}
...
Pkey = await generateKey(pass, iter);
```

Comment: But, keep in mind that this function will STILL return a promise and the caller of this function will still have to use `.then()` or `await` to get the resolved value from the promise this function returns.